# How to set stream bit-rate in KURENTO call?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, gstreamer, kurento

I'm investigating Kurento Media Server 6 and now playing with Tutorials. I have noticed that quality of stream is very poor. I have switched to higher resolution but issue remains. I'm connected to server in network with bandwidth 100/100mbps and stream must be crystal clear.I think somethere in settings of KMS 6 default bit-rate are set.I tried to find in documentation and in tutorials some kind of method which sets bit-rate, but did not found. How and there I can change default bit-rate of stream(if it is possible)?

As was suggested bellow I tried to set bandwith in nodejs one-to-many demo server.js on presenter creation:

```
webRtcEndpoint.setMinVideoSendBandwidth(1000, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            stop(sessionId);
            return callback(error);
        }                   
});
```

Quality still very poor, nothing changed at all(Demo server was restarted to reflect changes in code). Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 5):

KMS, by default, restricts BW for WebRTC endpoints to 500Kbps and restricts BW on transcodings to 300Kbps. You can modify these defaults through the following settings:

On your sending WebRtcEndpoints:

```
WebRtcEndpoint#setMaxVideoSendBandwidth(max_bw_in_kbps)
```

On any media element making a transcoding:

```
MediaElement#setOutputBitrate(outbut_bitrate_in_bps)
```

Take a look to [kms-core KMD](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-core/blob/master/src/server/interface/core.kmd.json) for having further information on these properties and methods

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have tried to set it in nodejs onetomany tutorial this way, but result is same no changes(server was restarted), am I on wrong way? webRtcEndpoint.setMaxVideoSendBandwidth(1000, function(error) {
     if (error) {
      stop(sessionId);
      return callback(error);
     }     
    });
    console.log("Bandwith is: " + webRtcEndpoint.getMaxVideoSendBandwidth().toString);

Comment: Same problem here, video bandwidth settings don't seem to have any impact on video quality. 
What happens in KMS if the input bandwidth goes below MinVideoRecvBandwidth?